# Django & Postgres - Index Row Size Exceeds btree version 4 maximum

Tags: django, postgresql

I have defined the following in `Django` to store an SSL certificate in plain-text PEM format:

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    pem = models.CharField(max_length=4096, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

When populating the table column in `Postgres`, I'm seeing this error which says the size of the data is too large for the b-tree index:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index row size 2720 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "app_certificate_pem_key"
DETAIL:  Index row references tuple (1,6) in relation "app_certificate".
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

Is there a "Django" way to create a unique index based on a hash of my pem column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your index width is exceeded. Try to [drop the index](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-drop-index/) for the pem field.

Comment: Well, I would still like to use an index.

Comment: In that case add another field, something like `pem_short = models.CharField(max_length=2048, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)` then in your view assign it as the first 2000 characters of the pem field. Then index by the short field.